# java couldn't take 2 continuous String input from user

Tags: java

This code in java

boknam [variable] refers to bookname & bokauthor[variable] referes to bookAuthor just not to get confused [ this is not that point here]

**Code**

```
                String boknam;
                String bokauthor;
                System.out.print("Enter bookNAme: ");
                boknam = scan.nextLine();
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.print("Enter bookAuthor: ");
                bokauthor = scan.nextLine();
```

Here I want user to **give input bookname & bookauthor** but the output is
[image]
I

IT **skips to take the input as bookNAme**, it is only taking input as bookAuthor,
please help will be aprreciated

```
               System.out.print("Enter bookNAme: ");
                boknam = scan.nextLine();
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.print("Enter bookAuthor: ");
                bokauthor = scan.nextLine();
```

boknam = scan.nextLine();
This line here is not working, not asking for input
**NOTE:- THE VARIABLE IS ALREADY ASSIGNED TO DON'T SAY YOU DIDNT INITIALIZED A STRING boknam**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes, we have to clear the buffer after getting integer input. Here, after getting your **Choice** input, we have to clear the buffer so just add an extra line `scan.nextLine()` before `boknam = scan.nextLine();` and that should work just fine.